# How to update textview text(server data) with time interval?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I want to update data in Textview text with 5 second interval. The data should comes for server. I call the "handler" with 15000 ms interval.

Problem is few times app crass due to call handler. Please tell me is there any other process to update data with time interval. I am sending the following code which I have used.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                         if(dataFromLogin.trim().equals("yes"))
                         {
                             checkUrlToFetchData(personLoginName);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             checkUrlForExtraVideo(latestVideoID);
                             checkUrlToFetchDataCreaterLogin(personLoginName);
                         }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 15000);
```

=============================

```
void checkUrlToFetchData(final String useridt)
{

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllItemScreen.this);
    String url = "http://liveapp.99emailmarketing.com/notifications/index";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.v( "response:",response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonObj.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success == true)
                        {
                            JSONArray notifications = jsonObj.getJSONArray("notifications");
                            if(notifications.length()>0)
                            {
                                JSONObject jo= notifications.getJSONObject(0);
                                createNotification(jo.getString("message"));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String error = jsonObj.getString("error");
                            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.v( "try:",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id",userIdfromLogin);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
void checkUrlToFetchDataCreaterLogin(final String useridt)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Validation Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllItemScreen.this);
    String url = "http://liveapp.99emailmarketing.com/LiveNotifications/index";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the response string.
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, "response:"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.v( "response:",response);
                    try {
                        //Log.v( "try:","1");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonObj.getBoolean("success");
                        String profileimages="",profileimages1="",profileimages2="",profileimages3="",profileimages4="",profileimages5="";


                        if(success == true)
                        {
                            JSONArray notifications = jsonObj.getJSONArray("LiveNotifications");
                            if(notifications.length()>0)
                            {
                                JSONObject jo= notifications.getJSONObject(0);
                                createNotification(jo.getString("message"));
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String error = jsonObj.getString("error");
                            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.v( "try:",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id",userIdfromLogin);

            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
void checkUrlForExtraVideo(final String checkUrlForExtraVideo)
{

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllItemScreen.this);
    String url = "http://liveapp.99emailmarketing.com/user-videos/newvideo";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the response string.
                    //progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, "response:"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.v( "response:",response);
                    try {
                        //Log.v( "try:","1");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonObj.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success == true)
                        {
                            int newVideo = jsonObj.getInt("newVideo");
                            if(newVideo>0)
                            {
                                getResourceUriRecyclerViewtruenew(swipeRefreshLayout);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String error = jsonObj.getString("error");
                            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.v( "try:",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(AllItemScreen.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("video_id",latestVideoID);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: you need to make interface and when ever u need to update then just call ur interface to update data (with in a specific time).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some task for every 5 seconds , You can use

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do your task
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }.run();
```

Comment: can u explain ur answer bit more ?

Comment: call your method to get data inside the run() then set it to textview. This would be executed for every 5 seconds

Comment: u need to elaborate why , when and how not just put method inside run() etc etc ...

Comment: Ok. But please tell me am I call any service or any broadcast receiver ?

Comment: Because I have to call web-service and parse data in that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the 5-second timer

```
private Handler mCountdownHandler;

private final static int INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;

private Runnable mTimer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something
        ...
        ...
        // Reschedule the timer to execute after 5 seconds
        mCountdownHandler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
    }
};

private void startTimer() {
    stopTimer();
    mCountdownHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    mCountdownHandler.post(mTimer);
}

private void stopTimer() {
    if (mCountdownHandler != null) {
        mCountdownHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer);
        mCountdownHandler = null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to free the handler when you destroy the activity

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopTimer();
}
```